# No toma los valores directos de mi Base de Datos mi Select

Tags: php, html, mysql, php5

Realize mi BD con mi tabla principal "trabajador", y que dependen otras de ella un ejemplo es mi tabla **"nomina"** con los campos: **id_nomina y descripcion_nomina**, lo que pretendo con esto es que se inserte o modifique a través del ID y que muestre a la interfaz la descripción, hasta este punto no tengo ninguno problema ya que lo realiza.

Mi problema es el siguiente, esta es una parte de mi formulario para modificar los registros, es decir si yo anteriormente **ingrese "Quincenal" (con id_nomina= 2) quiero que al acceder a mi modulo de modificaciones me aparezca por defaul en mi select el valor que yo inserte que seria "Quincenal" el problema que tengo es que no me aparece el que yo inserte, me aparece el primer registro que esta dado de alta en mi tabla de "nomina" ("Semanal=1")**, no me respeta los valores que se le insertaron previamente en la BD.

**¿Como le hago para que respete los datos del select que previamente se habían ingresado y al guardar respete esos campos?**

```html
  
  <?php
  extract($_GET);
  require("connect_db.php");

  $sql="SELECT * FROM trabajador  WHERE id_control=$id_control";
 //la variable  $mysqli viene de connect_db que lo traigo con el require("connect_db.php");
  $ressql=mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
  while ($row=mysqli_fetch_row ($ressql)){
       $id_control=$row[0];
    
  }
  
       $nombre=$row[1];
    $ap_paterno=$row[2];
    $ap_materno=$row[3];
    $NSS=$row[4];
    $CURP=$row[5];
    $RFC=$row[6];
    $id_puesto=$row[7];
    $id_area=$row[8];
    $idctg_turno=$row[9];
    $idctg_empresa=$row[10];
    $id_nomina=$row[11];
      
      }



  ?>

  <form action="ejecutaactualizar_trabajador.php" method="post">
    No. Control:<br><input type="text" name="id_control" value= "<?php echo $id_control?>" readonly="readonly"><br>
    Nombre:<br> <input type="text" name="nombre" value="<?php echo $nombre?>"><br>
    Apellido Paterno:<br> <input type="text" name="ap_paterno" value="<?php echo $ap_paterno?>"><br>
    Apellido Materno:<br> <input type="text" name="ap_materno" value="<?php echo $ap_materno?>"><br>
    NSS:<br> <input type="text" name="NSS" value="<?php echo $NSS?>"><br>
    CURP:<br> <input type="text" name="CURP" value="<?php echo $CURP?>"><br>
    RFC:<br> <input type="text" name="RFC" value="<?php echo $RFC?>"><br>
    Puesto:<br> <input type="text" name="id_puesto" value="<?php echo $id_puesto?>"><br>
    



<label>Tipo de Puesto</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_puesto, descripcion_puesto FROM puesto";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_puesto]\">$row[descripcion_puesto] </option>";   
   
}
?>

     
<select type="text"  id="id_area" name="id_area" placeholder="Area" required>

<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>



    
 


<label>Tipo de Área</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_area, descripcion_area FROM area";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_area]\">$row[descripcion_area] </option>";   
   
}
?>

     
<select type="text"  id="id_area" name="id_area" placeholder="Area" required>

<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>

 
  
<label>Tipo de Turno</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT idctg_turno, descripcion FROM ctg_turno";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[idctg_turno]\">$row[descripcion] </option>";   
   
}
?>
    
<select type="text"  id="idctg_turno" name="id_ctg_turno" placeholder="Turno" required>

<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
    






    
<label>Tipo de Empresa</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT idctg_empresa, descripcion_empresa FROM empresa";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[idctg_empresa]\">$row[descripcion_empresa] </option>";   
   
}
?>

     
<select type="text"  id="id_empresa" name="id_empresa" placeholder="Empresa" required>

<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>





 
    
   

<label>Tipo de Nómina</label>
<?php
require("connect_db.php");

$query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_nomina, descripcion_nomina FROM nomina";
$res = $mysqli->query($query);
$option = '';
while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){

    $option.="<option value=\"$row[id_nomina]\">$row[descripcion_nomina] </option>";   
   
}
?>

     
<select type="text"  id="id_nomina" name="id_nomina" placeholder="Nomina" required>

<?php echo $option; ?>
</select>
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    
    <br>
    <input type="submit" value="Guardar" class="btn btn-success btn-primary">
   </form>

      
  
  
  <div class="span8">
  
  </div> 
  </div> 
  <br/>

 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: El select del tipo de nómina es el que quieres que respete el último valor entrado???

Comment: De echo son varios select puesto, area, turno, empresa y nomina pero puse  como ejemplo solo el de nomina. Necesito  que en mi modulo de modificaciones me aparezca el que yo inserte, me respete ese dato y que no me aparezca el primero que esta dado de alta en esa tabla.

Comment: Intenta en tus consultas **selects** ordenar decrecientemente por la llave primaria de la tabla

Comment: De echo están ordenadas de esa forma, como están  en mi BD

Comment: Si estan ordenados tal y como estan en tu base de datos y tu clave primaria es por ejemplo id_nomina los registros estarian ordenados de menor a mayor por ese campo y no como te lo recomendé que lo ordenaras a la hora del select. La idea es que la última nómina que ingreses va ser la que mayor valor tendrá en su clave primaria si ordenas descendentemente esta será la primera en salir cuando muestres tu <select>

Comment: Creo que no entiendo la pregunta, ¿te refieres a salir el primero con que esté seleccionado en el select? si es así, lo que debes hacer es en cada vuelta de bucle por registro, comprobar si es el seleccionado y si lo es, marcarlo como checked. Confirma y te pongo un ejemplo en la respuesta.

Comment: @track3r Si a eso me refiero que muestre y respete el valor del select seleccionado

Comment: @track3r Me refiero si anteriormente guarde en mi base de datos para el campo nomina "Quincenal=Id 2" que me respete ese valor en mi select cuando quiero modificar mas no que cuando modifique me de el primer valor de mi tabla que seria "Semanal = id 1".

Comment: Sigo sin entenderlo, ¿en el select se cargan todos los registros, no? ¿y no es uno de ellos el que quieres? entonces es questión de identificarlo y marcarlo como seleccionado (atributo selected) puede que te refieras a que no está en el select, o que no se empareja con su id correspondiente. Te pongo una respuesta y si no es eso, la borro.

Comment: @track3r ¿en el select se cargan todos los registros, no? Es correcto en el select  se xcargan todos los registros pero quiero que los tome de la base de datos.   ¿y no es uno de ellos el que quieres?  Si es uno de ellos pero quiero que al darle click en el moton para modificar me jale el que yo inserte es decir si yo inserte Quincenal, que por defaul me de "Quincenal" pero tambien si quiero modificarlo que muestre la lista en el select de todo lo que tengo en ese campo

Answer (score 0):

Te pongo un ejemplo en uno de los bloques para que veas la idea.

Teniendo las declaraciones iniciales $id_puesto=$row[7];

```
<label>Tipo de Puesto</label>
<?php
    require("connect_db.php");

    $query = "SELECT DISTINCT id_puesto, descripcion_puesto FROM puesto";
    $res = $mysqli->query($query);
    $option = '';
    while ($row = $res->fetch_assoc()){
        if($id_puesto == $row["id_puesto"]) {
            $option.="<option selected value='".$row["id_puesto"]."'>".$row["descripcion_puesto"]."</option>";
        } else {
            $option.="<option value='".$row["id_puesto"]."'>".$row["descripcion_puesto"]."</option>";
        }

    }
?>
```

Lo que hago es identificar el registro del trabajador por medio de su id y cuando coincide, muestro el option con un [atributo selected](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_option_selected.asp) que lo dejará marcado o seleccionado.

Comment: Ok, si a eso es a lo que me refiero pero me muestra un error en el codigo Notice: Use of undefined constant id_puesto - assumed 'id_puesto' in C:\xampp\htdocs\concorde\actualizar_trabajador.php on line 155

Comment: Corregido, prueba ahora

Comment: Estimado, me sigue tomando el primer valor que se encuentra en mi tabla Nomina con el valor "Semanal"= id_nomina 1 mas no el valor con el que se inserto el registro que es "Quincena" = idnomina 2

Comment: Si examinas el HTML generado desde el insepctor de elementos, el código fuente de la página, firebug o similares, ¿ves si el option que toca está selected? ¿están todos? ¿ninguno?

Comment: No, de echo no me aparece ninguno

Comment: Si tienes acceso a phpmyadmin, ¿qué retorna la select directamente? SELECT DISTINCT id_puesto, descripcion_puesto FROM puesto

Comment: Si tengo acceso a phpmyadmin, Me muestra los ID y los Puesto que estan resguistrados

Comment: Revisando tu código, veo que te sobra un } al inicio durante las declaraciones, entre ellas $id_puesto, depura su contenido porque al parecer no contiene nada.

Comment: También deberías comprobar la SQL SELECT * FROM trabajador  WHERE id_control=$id_control, podría estar devolviendo siempre el mismo registro, ninguno o cualquier cosa. En ese caso habría que depurar $id_control